# How to print one-dimensional array elements using a FOR loop

Tags: c#

I am working on crafting a FOR loop to display the elements out of a one-dimensional array.

I have been tasked with using a FOR loop. Not a foreach loop. I have tried nesting the foreach loop inside the for loop and vice versa... to no avail. Additionally, I also need to use the GetUpperBound() method within the for loop structure.

```
        int Upper = Tally.GetUpperBound(0);
        int Lower = Tally.GetLowerBound(0);

        int RollNumber = 1;


        Console.WriteLine("Roll\t\tCount\t\t");

        for (int Count = 0; Count <= Upper; ++Count)
        {
            if (RollNumber < 13)
            {
                ++RollNumber;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t\t{1}\t\t", RollNumber, /* what goes here */ );
        }
```

I am wondering 1) if what I am trying to do is even possible and 2) how to essentially incrementally list the integers contained within the elements of the array with one WriteLine statement... I am a novice and if anyone can help point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated. Or if you need any other information to help me do what I want to do, then just let me know.

Comment: Isn't it just `Tally[Count]` or `Tally[RollNumber]` (depending on what you actually want to do)?

Comment: To be fair, I didnt know that I could utilize the variable that I used in the for loop structure like that. I thought that the Tally[____] was for things only related to the array functions or inside the array. Im still learning. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose `Tally` is your array, judging by the `GetLowerBound()` usage. I am still not exactly sure what you're currently doing, but if you want to print the elements of a one-dimensional array, here is your solution:

```
var array = new int[10]; // Tally in your case

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}: {array[i]}"); // Print "[line number]: [element]".
    // Console.WriteLine(array[i]); // Print element only.
}
```

If you absolutely need to use `GetLowerBound()` and `GetUpperBound()`(which is an absolute overhead for one-dimensional arrays and not needed at all):

```
var array = new int[10];

var lowerBound = array.GetLowerBound(0);
var upperBound = array.GetUpperBound(0);

for (int i = lowerBound; i <= upperBound; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}: {array[i]}"); // Print "[line number]: [element]".
    // Console.WriteLine(array[i]); // Print element only.
}
```

In both solutions, the printing of the elements:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}: {array[i]}");
```

depends on their type. For simple types like numbers and strings(like in your case), this would be sufficient. If the contained items are objects, you have to customize this as currently it will just use the default `.ToString()` method and print the object type.

```
Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}: {array[i]}");
```

is equivalent to:

```
Console.WriteLine((i + 1) + ": " + array[i]);
```

and

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", i + 1, array[i]));
```

or simply:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i + 1, array[i]);
```

Also, strive not to name your variables in PascalCase, or in other words, starting with a capital letter. This is reserved for other purposes(like Properties, Methods, Classes and such, but this is out of your scope for the time). Use [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case).

---

Lastly, in order to fix your solution, you can ditch the `RollNumber` variable and utilize the `Count` to both use it as an index to iterate over the array and also as a pointer for the current element(or row number).

```
int Upper = Tally.GetUpperBound(0); // This is equal to Tally.Length
int Lower = Tally.GetLowerBound(0); // This is equal to 0.

Console.WriteLine("Roll\t\tCount\t\t");

for (int Count = Lower; Count <= Upper; Count++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t\t{1}\t\t", Count + 1, Tally[Count]);
}
```

---

EDIT after comment:

An array is a structure which wraps elements. So basically you have a collection of items. In the context of an array, you can access each individual element by index. It's important to note here that indeces start from 0, not from 1. So, in short:
 `array[0]` would return the first item in the array, `array[1]` will return the second item.. up until `array[array.length-1]` which will return the last item in the array. 
You can utilize the "Count" variable as an index to iterate over the collection, because it changes its value from Lower(which is basically 0) - which corresponds to the first item in the array and sequentially increments its value until Upper(array.length - 1), which corresponds to the highest index in the array(or the last item).

Here you can find more info about [Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/), their inner workings and how to perform operations over them. The article is C# specific, but the context of arrays and operations over them are valid for almost all programming languages.

Comment: amazing! The last section of the code you suggested worked perfectly for what I wanted it to do!! Thank you so much! Is there anyway that you may be able to explain to me how the Count variable was able to work within the Tally[Count]? It allowed me to display the integers that were contained within the array elements.

Comment: Also, thanks for the tips on variable names... I think I see a trend of just using single letters or smaller easier variable labels. I will start doing that in the future! Thanks for everything.

Comment: @CodetheNalgene I have edited my answer to include this information because the comment section won't be enough. Hope it helps. Check the 'EDIT after comment' section.

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to display the contents of an array using your requirements (using *for* loop, and *GetUpperBound*)

```
int[] Tally = new int[] { 100, 200, 300, 400 };
for (int i = 0; i <= Tally.GetUpperBound(0); ++i) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", i, Tally[i]);
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ie2pJz